# The correct way to display key-value pairs in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, key-value

I have a table view. Maybe with cells with `UITableViewCellStyle1`, it doesn't matter.

Also I have a list of items to display, for a quick exapmle as below:

```
Gender — Male
Age — 18
Height — 175 cm
```

and so on for a different set of data. Maybe a class `Human` with properties `GenderType gender`, `NSInteger age`, `float height`. And I want it to represent it as above. Also this approach should be flexible, I want to reorder those values in my way fast and clear. Without using of CoreData.

First and quick solution is to make two dictionaries and link them as in DB:

```objective-c
NSDictionary *keys = @{@0 : @"Gender", @1 : @"Age", @2 : @"Height"};
NSDictionary *values = @{@0 : @"Male", @1 : @18, @2 : @"175 cm"};
NSArray *source = @[@0, @1, @2]; // My order
```

---

Now I've come to use `Pair` class with properties as below.

```objective-c
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *key;
@property(nonatomic, strong) id value;

-(id)initWithKey:(NSString *)key value:(id)value;
```

Now code looks like

```objective-c
Pair *genderPair = [[Pair alloc] initWithKey:@"Gender" value:@"Male"];
Pair *agePair = [[Pair alloc] initWithKey:@"Age" value:@18];
Pair *heightPair = [[Pair alloc] initWithKey:@"Height" value:@175];
NSArray *tableItems = [genderPair, agePair, heightPair];
```

It looks like more clear but... I think this is not the best solution (and there are no class Pair but guys make settings-like tables with switches or whatever, but they do it somehow). I believe that a lot of people trying to do this and there should be at least a better or general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class:

```
@interface Human : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* male; // Or a BOOL if you prefer it 
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber* age; 
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber* height; // Or NSString if you prefer it
                                 // Consider that you may always format the number

- (id) initWithAge: (NSNumber*) age height: (NSNumber*) height male: (NSNUmber*) male;

@end
```

You can always ask for an object's keys:

```
Human* human=[[Human alloc] initWithAge: @20 height: @178 male: @YES];
NSNumber* age= [human valueForKey: @"age"];
```

**EDIT**

Pardon, I totally misunderstood your question.Then if you always use the same position for the attributes in the array, I think there isn't a better way to do it.
You can find the attribute for every row easily, so you also easily return the table view cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: nil];
    Pair* pair= tableItems[ [indexPath indexAtPosition: 1] ];
    cell.textLabel.text= pair.key;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", pair.value];
    return cell;
}
```

That's O(1): a NSArray isn't a linked list, you access to tableItems[index] in O(1) to read the attribute.

Comment: Key there is a description string written with bold type in table view. I already have this class, it's the question how to format output for this class in a table.

Comment: You're asking what's the best way to implement the data source, starting from this class?

Comment: Yes, the data source for cells' titles and values for titles. Values are stored in the class. Now I want to link them to titles.

Comment: That's a table view made with OS X: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/screenshot20121225at558.png/ Are you looking for the same in iOS?

Comment: No. Just a simple `UItTableView` with title and subititle.